# Error when trying to write a matplotlib plot from Pandas DataFrame to pdf

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, pdfpages

I'm trying to write a plot from matplotlib to a pdf file but getting an error.

I'm creating a plot using matplotlib from a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
bplot = dfbuild.plot(x='Build',kind='barh',stacked='True')
```

From the documentation: http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#save-multiple-plots-to-one-pdf-file

It seems like I should be doing it this way:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
pp = PdfPages(r'c:\temp\page.pdf')
figure = bplot.fig
pp.savefig(figure)
pp.close()
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'fig'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `dfbuild.plot` returns an `AxesSubplot` and not a `Figure` instance, which is required by the `savefig` function.

This solves the issue:

```
pp.savefig(bplot.figure)
```

Answer (score 0):

I works when I do it this way.

```
pp = PdfPages(r'c:\temp\page.pdf')
dfbuild.plot(x=['Build','Opperator'],kind='barh',stacked='True')
pp.savefig()
pp.close()
```

From [Saving plots to pdf files using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364405/saving-plots-to-pdf-files-using-matplotlib)